# WP Rest API feature image breaking react component

Tags: posts, javascript, rest-api

I have a react app which displays posts by using the WP Rest APi.

To display, I'm using map() to loop through the posts.

```
        {posts.map((articles, i) => {
            return (
                <Post
                key={posts[i].id}
                id={posts[i].id}
                title = {posts[i].title.rendered}
                link = {posts[i].link}         
                img = {posts[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url}
                category = {posts[i].categories}
                />
            )
        })
    }
```

Because the first post doesn't have a featured image, the component breaks and I get the following console error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

If I remove the img prop, there are no issues, everything displays correctly.

Do I need to wrap the img prop into a conditional?
Can you please advise on how I can fix the issue?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This is really just a JavaScript question. Yes you need to check for the existence of object properties before accessing them. This is easier if you use optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I've added the ? but still not working.
img = {post?._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

If no feature image exists, then _embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] is not used.

To resolve, the prop value needs to be wrapped into a conditional.

```
<Post
key={post?.id}
id={post?.id}
title = {post?.title.rendered}
link = {post?.link}
img = {post && post._embedded && post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] ? post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url : ' ' }
category = {post?.categories}
/>
```